# Why doesn't my struct live long enough?

Tags: rust, lifetime

In Rust, I get the following error:

```
<anon>:14:9: 14:17 error: `mystruct` does not live long enough
<anon>:14         mystruct.update();
                  ^~~~~~~~
<anon>:10:5: 17:6 note: reference must be valid for the lifetime 'a as defined on the block at 10:4...
<anon>:10     {
<anon>:11         let initial = vec![Box::new(1), Box::new(2)];
<anon>:12         let mystruct = MyStruct { v : initial, p : &arg };
<anon>:13         
<anon>:14         mystruct.update();
<anon>:15         
          ...
<anon>:12:59: 17:6 note: ...but borrowed value is only valid for the block suffix following statement 1 at 12:58
<anon>:12         let mystruct = MyStruct { v : initial, p : &arg };
<anon>:13         
<anon>:14         mystruct.update();
<anon>:15         
<anon>:16         mystruct
<anon>:17     }
error: aborting due to previous error
```

for the following code:

```rust
struct MyStruct<'a>
{
    v : Vec<Box<i32>>,
    p : &'a i32
}

impl<'a> MyStruct<'a>
{
    fn new(arg : &'a i32) -> MyStruct<'a>
    {
        let initial = vec![Box::new(1), Box::new(2)];
        let mystruct = MyStruct { v : initial, p : &arg };

        mystruct.update();

        mystruct
    }

    fn update(&'a mut self)
    {
        self.p = &self.v.last().unwrap();
    }

}

fn main() {
    let x = 5;
    let mut obj = MyStruct::new(&x);
}
```

[(Playground)](http://is.gd/IqMGWt)

I don't understand why `mystruct` does not live enough. If I comment out the `mystruct.update()` line it works fine though. What's more is, if I comment out the body of `update` the code still fails. Why does calling an empty function which borrows a mutable `self` changes things?

I don't understand which reference is the one the error talks about. Can somebody explain this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reference this error talks about is the one which is implicitly created when you call `update()`. Because `update()` takes `&'a mut self`, it means that it accepts a value of type `&'a mut MyStruct<'a>`. It means that in theory you should call `update()` like this:

```
(&mut mystruct).update();
```

It would be very inconvenient to write this everywhere, and so Rust is able to automatically insert necessary `&`s, `&mut`s and `*`s in order to call a method. This is called "autoreference", and the only place it happens is method invocations/field access.

The problem is the definition of `update()` method:

```rust
impl<'a> MyStruct<'a> {
    ...
    fn update(&'a mut self) { ... }
    ...
}
```

Here you are requesting that `update()` receives the value it is called at via a reference with lifetime `'a`, where `'a` is the lifetime of the reference stored in the structure.

However, when you have a structure value you're calling this method on, there should be already a reference to `i32` you stored in this structure. Hence the lifetime of the structure value is strictly smaller than the lifetime designated by the lifetime parameter, so it is just impossible to construct `&'a mut MyStruct<'a>` with local variables (as in your case).

The solution is to use `&mut self` instead of `&'a mut self`:

```rust
fn update(&mut self) { ... }
// essentially equivalent to
fn update<'b>(&'b mut self) where 'a: 'b { ... }
// `'b` is a fresh local lifetime parameter
```

This way the lifetime of the structure in this method call is not tied to the reference this structure contains and can be smaller.

More in-depth explanation follows below.

By itself your definition is not nonsense. For example:

```rust
struct IntRefWrapper<'a> {
    value: &'a i32
}

static X: i32 = 12345;
static Y: IntRefWrapper<'static> = IntRefWrapper { value: &X };

impl<'a> IntRefWrapper<'a> {
    fn update(&'a self) { ... }
}

Y.update();
```

Here `update()` invocation won't cause compilation errors because both lifetimes (of `Y` and of `X`, reference to which is contained in `Y`) are `'static`.

Let's consider your example, for comparison:

```rust
impl<'a> MyStruct<'a> {
    fn new(arg : &'a i32) -> MyStruct<'a> {
        let initial = vec![Box::new(1), Box::new(2)];
        let mystruct = MyStruct { v : initial, p : &arg };

        mystruct.update();

        mystruct
    }
}
```

Here we have a lifetime parameter, `'a`, which is supplied by the *caller* of the function. For example, the caller could call this function with a static reference:

```rust
static X: i32 = 12345;

MyStruct::new(&X);  // here &X has static lifetime
```

However, when `update()` method is invoked, `mystruct` lifetime is bounded by the block it is called in:

```rust
{
    let initial = vec![Box::new(1), Box::new(2)];
    let mystruct = MyStruct { v : initial, p : &arg };  // +
                                                        // |
    mystruct.update();                                  // |
                                                        // |
    mystruct                                            // |
}
```

Naturally, the borrow checker can't prove that this lifetime is the same as the lifetime provided by the caller (and for any possible "external" lifetime it is indeed impossible for them to match), so it throws an error.

When update is defined like this:

```rust
fn update(&mut self) { ... }
// or, equivalently
fn update<'b>(&'b mut self) where 'a: 'b { ... }
```

then when you call it, it is no longer required that the value you call this method on must live exactly as long as `'a` - it is sufficient for it to live for any lifetime which is smaller than or equal to `'a` - and the lifetime inside the function perfectly matches these requirements. Thus you can call such method on your value, and the compiler won't complain.

Additionally (as noticed in the comments) the following line is indeed invalid and there is no way around it:

```
self.p = &self.v.last().unwrap();
```

The borrow check fails here because you're trying to store a reference with lifetime of the structure into the structure itself. In general this can't be done because it has nasty soundness issues. For example, suppose you were indeed able to store this reference into the structure. But now you can't mutate `Vec<Box<i32>>` in the structure because it may destroy an element which the previously stored references points at, making the code memory unsafe.

It is impossible to check for such things statically, and so it is disallowed on the borrow checking level. In fact, it is just a nice consequence of general borrow checking rules.

Comment: 1) I think you're wrong on lifetime bounds: the syntax is `'long: 'short` (for
`'long` outlives `'short`). Thus, it should be written `fn update<'b>(&'b mut
self) where 'a: 'b { ... }` http://is.gd/EEKFnB

Comment: 2) It doesn't address the line `self.p = &self.v.last().unwrap();` which fails
to compile. The explanation is that the reference taken precisely at this line
doesn't live further than the block in `update()`, which the borrow checker
correctly rejects. http://is.gd/mlhHvb

Comment: @mdup, indeed, you're right about the lifetimes syntax. Somehow I thought it was the other way around. `'a: 'b` should be read as "`'a` is at least as long as `'b`", then everything starts making sense.

Comment: @mdup, the line in `update()` fails not because the reference does not live further than the block. It fails because this reference would point into the structure itself, and this is impossible in Rust.

Comment: Thanks, this was a very helpful answer! I was indeed trying to make the update fail by making the pointer point into the structure itself. However, I do not remember seeing the `'a: 'b` notation in the Rust Programming Language book. Where is this documented? I can't also find it in the reference.

Comment: @loudandclear, frankly, I don't know :) I believe I saw this in someone else's code a long time ago. It is quite possible that this notation is not documented yet.

Comment: Thank you! This really helped clear up what I was experiencing in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30488928/1483396) post.