# How to do error handling in Rust and what are the common pitfalls?

Tags: error-handling, rust

I noticed that Rust does not have exceptions. How to do error handling in Rust and what are the common pitfalls? Are there ways to control flow with raise, catch, reraise and other stuff? I found inconsistent information on this.

Comment: Did you have had a look at this: https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/error-handling.html

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Rust generally solves errors in two ways:

- **Unrecoverable errors**. Once you `panic!`, that's it. Your program or thread aborts because it encounters something it can't solve and its invariants have been violated. E.g. if you find invalid sequences in what should be a UTF-8 string.
- **Recoverable errors**. Also called failures in some documentation. Instead of panicking, you emit a [`Option<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) or [`Result<T, E>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html). In these cases, you have a choice between a valid value `Some(T)`/`Ok(T)` respectively or an invalid value `None`/`Error(E)`. Generally `None` serves as a `null` replacement, showing that the value is missing.

---

Now comes the hard part. Application.

### Unwrap

Sometimes dealing with an `Option` is a pain in the neck, and you are almost guaranteed to get a value and not an error.

In those cases it's perfectly fine to use `unwrap`. `unwrap` turns `Some(e)` and `Ok(e)` into `e`, otherwise it panics. Unwrap is a tool to turn your recoverable errors into unrecoverable.

```
if x.is_some() {
    y = x.unwrap(); // perfectly safe, you just checked x is Some
    // ...
}
```

Inside the `if`-block it's perfectly fine to unwrap since it should never panic because we've already checked that it is `Some` with `x.is_some()`.

If you're writing a library, using `unwrap` is discouraged because when it panics the user cannot handle the error. Additionally, a future update may change the invariant. Imagine if the example above had `if x.is_some() || always_return_true()` . The invariant would changed, and `unwrap` could panic.

In this example, you should use [`ìf let`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-03-if-let.html) instead:

```
if let Some(y) = x {
    // ...
}
```

### `?` operator / `try!` macro

What's the `?` operator or the `try!` macro? A short explanation is that it either returns the value inside an `Ok()` or prematurely returns error.

Here is a simplified definition of what the operator or macro expand to:

```
macro_rules! try {
    ($e:expr) => (match $e {
        Ok(val) => val,
        Err(err) => return Err(err),
    });
}
```

If you use it like this:

```
let x = File::create("my_file.txt")?;
```

```
let x = try!(File::create("my_file.txt"));
```

It will convert it into this:

```
let x = match File::create("my_file.txt") {
    Ok(val)  => val,
    Err(err) => return Err(err),
};
```

The downside is that your functions now return `Result`.

### Combinators

[`Option`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html) and [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html) have some convenience methods that allow chaining and dealing with errors in an understandable manner. Methods like `and`, `and_then`, `or`, `or_else`, `ok_or`, `map_err`, etc.

For example, you could have a default value in case your value is botched.

```
let x: Option<i32> = None;
let guaranteed_value = x.or(Some(3)); //it's Some(3)
```

Or if you want to turn your `Option` into a `Result`.

```
let x = Some("foo");
assert_eq!(x.ok_or("No value found"), Ok("foo"));

let x: Option<&str> = None;
assert_eq!(x.ok_or("No value found"), Err("No value found"));
```

---

This is just a brief skim of things you can do. For more explanation, check out:

- http://blog.burntsushi.net/rust-error-handling/
- https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-00-error-handling.html
- http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2014/10/16/on-error-handling/

Comment: Be warry of the burntsushi reader exercise of converting the iterative loop into an iterator. It's [not that simple](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30488928/1483396)

Comment: For the `?` or `try!` method, also see the "anyhow" crate - it makes it super elegant to do this by allowing you to attach a context to the error.

Answer (score 4):

If you need to terminate some independent execution unit (a web request, a video frame processing, a GUI event, a source file to compile) but not all your application in completeness, there is a function [std::panic::catch_unwind](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html) that invokes a closure, capturing the cause of an unwinding panic if one occurs.

```
let result = panic::catch_unwind(|| {
    panic!("oh no!");
});
assert!(result.is_err());
```

I would not grant this closure write access to any variables that could outlive it, or any other otherwise global state.

The documentation also says the function also may not be able to catch some kinds of panic.

Comment: This is not a proper way to handle errors in Rust. Not only `catch_unwind` doesn't catch anything if there is no unwinding (ie. if your panics abort), so you might miss something, but you will also catch a lot of stuff you don't know how to handle (ie. OOM).