# Rust std::net::UdpSocket no method named recv_from

Tags: rust, udp

I am working off a [simple example](https://hanckmann.com/2016/07/05/rust-and-udp.html) for creating a rust udp client/server application. But when trying to use either the send_to or recv_from methods I get the following error:

[E0599] no method named `send_to` found for type `std::result::Result<std::net::UdpSocket, std::io::Error>` in the current scope.

I havent altered the cargo.toml file in any way however I did not expect I would have to as I am using the standard library with rust version 1.35.0.

Both the client and server were created using cargo new [filename] --bin and the code is in main.rs

Client

```
use std::net::{Ipv4Addr, SocketAddrV4, UdpSocket};
use std::io;

fn snd()  -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    // Define the local connection (to send the data from)
    let ip = Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1);
    let connection = SocketAddrV4::new(ip, 9992);

    // Bind the socket
    // let socket = try!(UdpSocket::bind(connection));
    let socket = UdpSocket::bind(connection);

    // Define the remote connection (to send the data to)
    let connection2 = SocketAddrV4::new(ip, 9991);

    // Send data via the socket
    let buf = &[0x01, 0x02, 0x03];
    socket.send_to(buf, &connection2);
    println!("{:?}", buf);

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    match snd() {
        Ok(()) => println!("All snd-ing went well"),
        Err(err) => println!("Error: {:?}", err),
    }
}
```

Server

```
use std::net::{Ipv4Addr, SocketAddrV4, UdpSocket};
use std::io;

fn recv()  -> Result<(), io::Error> {
    // Define the local connection information
    let ip = Ipv4Addr::new(127, 0, 0, 1);
    let connection = SocketAddrV4::new(ip, 9991);

    // Bind the socket
    // let socket = try!(UdpSocket::bind(connection));
    let socket = UdpSocket::bind(connection);

    // Read from the socket
    let mut buf = [0; 10];
    // let (amt, src) = try!(socket.recv_from(&mut buf));
    let (amt, src) = socket.recv_from(&mut buf).expect("Didn't recieve data");

    // Print only the valid data (slice)
    println!("{:?}", &buf[0 .. amt]);

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    match recv() {
        Ok(()) => println!("All recv-ing went well"),
        Err(err) => println!("Error: {:?}", err),
    }
}
```

I also get the following error on the sever side when using cargo build.

[E0599] no method named `recv_from` found for type `std::result::Result<std::net::UdpSocket, std::io::Error>` in the current scope.

Edit:
It seems this was a result of forgetting to handle the error handling in the return from UdpSocket::bind. This is talked about in more detail in the post
[How to do error handling in Rust and what are the common pitfalls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505639/how-to-do-error-handling-in-rust-and-what-are-the-common-pitfalls) as mentioned below.

Leaving this question mostly intact as I have not seen many questions or examples explicitly dealing with net::UdpSocket

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff, I really suggest reading [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) and especially the chapter about [error handling](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch09-02-recoverable-errors-with-result.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to do error handling in Rust and what are the common pitfalls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505639/how-to-do-error-handling-in-rust-and-what-are-the-common-pitfalls)

Comment: I have been going through the book however I'm still new to the concepts (like handling returns with error portion) so I overlooked it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let socket = UdpSocket::bind(connection);
```

This call returns `Result` which could represent success value or error value. `unwrap()` forces it to yield success value (content of `Ok`). It also panics in case there is error (value is `Err`).

```
let socket = UdpSocket::bind(connection).unwrap();
```

OR you can use expect as well which will print the message before panicking.

```
let socket = UdpSocket::bind(connection).expect("failed to bind host socket");
```