# Why isn't an error type implicitly converted when I return it?

Tags: error-handling, rust, type-conversion

The following code fails to compile

```
// winservice.rs

#[macro_use] extern crate err_derive;
extern crate windows_service;

use windows_service::service_manager::{ServiceManager, ServiceManagerAccess};

#[derive(Debug, Error)]
pub enum WinServiceError {
    #[error(display = "could not query windows services api")]
    WinApiError(windows_service::Error),
}

impl From<windows_service::Error> for WinServiceError {
    fn from(error: windows_service::Error) -> Self {
        WinServiceError::WinApiError(error)
    }
}

fn get_manager(request_access: ServiceManagerAccess) -> Result<ServiceManager, WinServiceError> {
    ServiceManager::local_computer(None::<&str>, request_access)
}

pub fn main() {
    // get_manager();
}
```

I am getting the error

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
   --> src/winservice.rs:186:5
    |
185 | fn get_manager(request_access: ServiceManagerAccess) -> Result<ServiceManager, Error> {
    |                                                         ----------------------------- expected `std::result::Result<windows_service::service_manager::ServiceManager, winservice::Error>` because of return type
186 |     ServiceManager::local_computer(None::<&str>, request_access)
    |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected enum `winservice::Error`, found enum `windows_service::Error`
    |
    = note: expected type `std::result::Result<_, winservice::Error>`
               found type `std::result::Result<_, windows_service::Error>`
```

Why isn't the Rust compiler [auto converting the return type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) from `windows_service::Error` to `winservice::Error`?

Comment: It's hard to answer your question because it doesn't include a [MRE]. Your error message is about line 185, but there's not 185 lines of code present. It would make it easier for us to help you if you try to reproduce your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) if possible, otherwise in a brand new Cargo project, then [edit] your question to include the additional info. There are [Rust-specific MRE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) you can use to reduce your original code for posting here. Thanks!

Comment: You've linked to the `From` trait but are not calling the `From` trait in any manner. It's not automatic, you have to invoke it (either by directly calling `From` or indirectly via the `?` operator).

Comment: You may be interested in [Rust proper error handling (auto convert from one error type to another with question mark)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48430836/155423); [How do you define custom `Error` types in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42584368/155423); [How to do error handling in Rust and what are the common pitfalls?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30505639/155423)

Comment: @Shepmaster Thank you for the suggestions. I will prepare a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @Shepmaster Regarding the comment that I am not calling `From` trait, the example code in the rust documentation page is also not calling `From` trait explicitly.

Comment: *the example code in the rust documentation page is also not calling `From` trait* — where? You'll need to be more specific. The very first example has `String::from`, calling the trait, but I'm not going to hand-check every code example.

Comment: @Shepmaster I was referring to the `open_and_parse_file` function in the second example. `fs::read_to_string` returns `std::io::Result<T, std::io::Error>`, whereas `open_and_parse_file` returns `Result<i32, CliError>`, yet `fs::read_to_string(&file_name)?;` within `open_and_parse_file` compiles successfully.

Comment: The documentation says, `The '?' operator automatically converts the underlying error type to our custom error type by calling Into<CliError>::into which is automatically provided when implementing From. The compiler then infers which implementation of Into should be used.` There is no explicit conversion.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199640/discussion-between-shepmaster-and-joyce-babu).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Shepmaster's help, I was able resolve the error.

I did not realize that I was returning the result object directly. I had to unwrap the result object for the conversion to work.

The following code attempts to return a value of type `Result<_, windows_services::Error>` as `Result<_, WinServiceError>`.

```
fn get_manager(request_access: ServiceManagerAccess) -> Result<ServiceManager, WinServiceError> {
    ServiceManager::local_computer(None::<&str>, request_access)
}
```

But the following code works, because we are now creating a new Result object of the correct signature, and rust compiler performs the conversion between the error types while creating the new object.

```
fn get_manager(request_access: ServiceManagerAccess) -> Result<ServiceManager, WinServiceError> {
    Ok(ServiceManager::local_computer(None::<&str>, request_access)?)
}
```