# How to read a list of numbers from a file into a Vec?

Tags: vector, rust, file-io, enums, numbers

I'm trying to read in a list of numbers from a file (where each line has a number on it) into a `Vec<i64>` with Rust. I can get the numbers loaded from the file as strings using a `BufReader`. However, I can't seem to get the value of the strings out of the `Result` enum they are wrapped in by the `BufReader`.

So how does one get those values out of `Result` to parse, so they can populate a `Vec` with another type than strings?

What I have tried:

1. Using a `for` loop where I can print the values to prove they're there, but it panics on the parse when I try to compile with the `numbers.append(...)` line.

```rust
fn load_from_file(file_path: &str) {
    let file = File::open(file_path).expect("file wasn't found.");
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let numbers: Vec<i64> = Vec::new();

    for line in reader.lines() {
        // prints just fine
        println!("line: {:?}", line);
        numbers.append(line.unwrap().parse::<i64>());
    }
}
```

2. Alternatively I tried mapping instead, but I encounter the same issue with getting the values into the `Vec<i64>` I'm trying to populate.

```rust
fn load_from_file(file_path: &str) {
    let file = File::open(file_path).expect("file wasn't found.");
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    let numbers: Vec<i64> = reader
        .lines()
        .map(|line| line.unwrap().parse::<i64>().collect());
}
```

This is not solved solely by [How to do error handling in Rust and what are the common pitfalls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505639/how-to-do-error-handling-in-rust-and-what-are-the-common-pitfalls)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do error handling in Rust and what are the common pitfalls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505639/how-to-do-error-handling-in-rust-and-what-are-the-common-pitfalls)

Comment: That's an informative question but doesn't help solve my problem or discuss Result, BufReader, etc

Comment: It goes over error handling in general, which primarily uses `Result`s. It goes over `.unwrap()`, the `?` operator for propagating errors (a shorthand for an `Ok`/`Err` match), and other transformative functions. You're right that it doesn't answer you directly, but I hope it gives you the tools necessary for handling errors in the future. `.unwrap()` is a blunt tool and not always the best choice.

Comment: @kmdreko Thank you for the explanation, that is a very helpful question/answer. For those newer to Rust it's difficult to pull out of that info what's needed to solve this kind of problem. That's why I think both questions are valuable, and not quite close enough to be a *duplicate* or *answered elsewhere*. I do see how closely related they are they are though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call the `unwrap()` method on `Result` enums to get values out of them. Fixed example:

```rust
use std::fs::File;
use std::io::BufReader;
use std::io::BufRead;

fn load_from_file(file_path: &str) {
    let file = File::open(file_path).expect("file wasn't found.");
    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    let numbers: Vec<i64> = reader
        .lines()
        .map(|line| line.unwrap().parse::<i64>().unwrap())
        .collect();
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=1c8b226ec2e07e8b2207bda55261e4c2)

Comment: So you have to unwrap the *line* to parse it, then unwrap again inside the map to then collect the values? Would mind explaining a little more on why you unwrap twice? Thanks

Comment: @CoderLee `.lines()` works over any buffered reader meaning individual lines can fail for IO reasons. Parsing the string into an i64 can also fail. Since they are both fallible, they both return `Result`s that must be handled (via `.unwrap()` in this case)