# Catch runtime errors in functions

Tags: rust

I'm exploring *Functional programming in Rust*. I've been reading that language provides an `Error` handler with the help of the `Result` type.

But when using functions, it might end up in runtime errors. Is there any way to specify that a function might have side effects?

Having this code as a reference:

```rust
fn map(self, func: fn(T) -> T) -> TryMonad<T>{
     match func(self.success.unwrap())   {
        Ok(v) => TryMonad { success: Some(v), failure:None},
        Err(error) => TryMonad { success: None, failure:Some(error)},
    }
}
```

Where `func` might throw an error.

Shall I consider if that happens it will be an unrecoverable `panic` error?

Comment: It sounds like you're approaching this from a very C++ perspective. Rust doesn't "throw" errors. `throw` isn't even a keyword in Rust. There are two ways to communicate errors in Rust: one is `Result` (as you've already found), and the other is panicking, from which there is no recovery. If a function doesn't return `Result`, then that function can only fail irrecoverably. There's no middle ground.

Comment: @SilvioMayolo Nit: there is [recovering](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/panic/fn.catch_unwind.html) from panics, and the mechanism is the same as for C++ exceptions (including the fact that it might not be available on all platforms/if you want to compile with `fno-exceptions`) — this doesn't change the fact that you wouldn't panic in Rust where you throw in C++.

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30505639/how-to-do-error-handling-in-rust-and-what-are-the-common-pitfalls) your question? It's probably not an identical question but it does go into the differences between panicing and returning `Result`

Comment: Thanks, I got the idea about no runtime errors, and I like it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, the problem here is that `self.success.unwrap()` panics when the variable is `None`. From the perspective of functional programming, the better approach is [pattern matching](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch06-02-match.html#matching-with-optiont):

```rust
fn map(self, func: fn(T) -> T) -> TryMonad<T> {
    match self {
        | TryMonad { success, failure: None } =>
            TryMonad { success: success.map(func), failure: None },
        | failed @ _ => failed, // return as is
    }
}
```

On error, we return `self` as is. Otherwise, we proceed with `Some(f(v))`.